# Access google drive spreadsheet in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to access a private google drive spreadsheet for my code in javascript. Is it possible? If access private spreadsheet is not possible, how do I access the public spreadsheet using javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

there's a project called [tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) that allows you parse data from a google spreadsheet